# How call function in .subscribe

Tags: angular

I need to execute the a function in case the ListPatients function is successful, where I should add it

```
this.dataApiService.ListPatients()
  .subscribe((
    data : PacienteInterface) =>(this.pacienteLista = data),
    error => this.mensajeError(error)
    );
```

Comment: In the call back: `=> { this.pacienteLista = data; this.someFunction(); } `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about that?

```
this.dataApiService.ListPatients()
    .subscribe((data: PacienteInterface) => {
        this.pacienteLista = data;
        // functionToCall();
    }, error => this.mensajeError(error));
```

Comment: well also check out the comments from @Igor